# Disable a Module in Certain magento Theme

Tags: magento

Is it possible to disable certain modules when running a certain theme? I'm working on a mobile friendly version of our Magento store and I've run into some issues with a few extensions. Rather than customize them, the default iphone theme is sufficient, so I'd like to just disable those modules so it runs the default code when on a mobile device. Is this possible?

Comment: No you can't disable modules according to theme by default although of course an extension could be made to do this.  In my opinion, customising the theme is actually a better solution anyway as different modules running under different themes is likely to cause confusion for someone at some point down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable that module in local.xml. Just paste this xml in your theme's local.xml.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Your_Module_Name]>
            <active>false</active>
        </[Your_Module_Name]>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel

```
system -> configuration -> advanced
```

here you can disable certain module